# Residue of $e^{1/z}/(z^2+1)$ at $0$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I want to calculate the following residue:

$$Res\left [ \frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z^{2}+1},0 \right ]$$
I did the following step
$$\lim_{z->0} z \frac{z+1}{z(z+i)(z-1)}=1$$
$$e^{\frac{1}{z}}=\sum \frac{1}{n!z^{n}}=1+\frac{1}{z}+o\left ( \frac{1}{z^{2}} \right )$$
$$\lim_{z->0} z \frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z^{2}+1}=\lim_{z->0} z \frac{z+1}{z(z+i)(z-i)}=1$$
However I think it's wrong. Where is my mistake?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong? If you already have an answer, then you should post it. It helps us to see, what is the right result.

Comment: $o(1/z^2)$ is useless for $z\to 0$

Comment: anyway, one way how to compute this residue is to use the fact that the sum of all the residues is $0$ - the residues at non-zero $z$'s are somewhat simpler in this case

Comment: I want to calculate $\gamma _{r}=Re^{i\vartheta }
|R|<1
\oint_{\gamma _{r}}\frac{e
^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z^{2}+1}$ bur the result is $2\pi iSin[1]$. I can't understand.

Comment: @StefanoBarone Your idea was very good: via Laurent series, and you were close. I wrote an answer, which gives the result you mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea...following yours: since we're interested in some neighborhood of $\;z=0\;$ and only in the coefficient of $\;z^{-1}\;$ in the corresponding Laurent series , we can assume $\;|z|<1\;$ , and then

$$\frac{e^{1/z}}{1+z^2}=(1-z^2+z^4-z^6+\ldots)\left(1+\frac1z+\frac1{2!z^2}+\frac1{3!z^3}+\ldots\right)=\frac1z-\frac1{3!z}+\ldots\implies$$

the wanted coefficient is

$$1-\frac1{3!}+\frac1{5!}-\frac1{7!}+\ldots=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)!}$$

Do you recognize the above sum? (Hint: trigonometry)

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer is fantastic, but I don't know if my solution is wrong or incomplete. The two results are not equivalent. Where is the wrong step from conceptual point of view?

Comment: @StefanoBarone I'm not sure I understand completely what you attempted, but I think you tried to evaluate the residue by means of those limits. Yet, I think you **must first** know what kind of (isolated) singularity you have (since derivatives of different orders enter in that calculation according ot the order of the pole...in case you have a pole). The formular you used: $\;\lim\limits_{z\to0}zf(z)\;$ helps **if** $\;z=0\;$  is a simple pole. Thus, I think going with Laurent series is simpler in cases like this one.